# Get CMYK values from image, change them, and save as new image - C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to load 8bit Tiff CMYK image at pixel level for image manipulation. Idea is to be able to change loaded C M Y K pixel components and save changes to new CMYK Tiff file. My question is how can this be done in c++, and which library is easy to use (installation process and API). I'm new to c++, but programming isnt new to me (hobby, but now I need it for student research). Its just more confusing to work in c++ compared to other languages, like Python for instance. So to repeat my question once more, how to do image manipulation for 8bit Tiff CMYK at pixel level with being able to change CMYK components for each pixel in c++, and please can you tell me what I need to install to accomplish that(free libraries only because it is for student research)? Can this be done with libraries that are in C++ Visual Studio 2010 express edition?

Thanks!

P.S. I've done all that in Python (manipulations saturation, desaturation, UCA, GCR, UCR) but now I need to do in a compiler language for comparison between two programs. I've tride to do it in c# but that cmyk barrier of not be able to do stuff with cmyk image also appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe CXImage will help http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/cximage.aspx